# How can I find $a$ and $b$ if I have half of the matrix ($2\times 2$), one eigenvector, and one eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How can I find $a$ and $b$ if I have half of the matrix ($2\times 2$), one eigenvector, and one eigenvalue?  The matrix is $2\times 2$:

$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 6 & a \\ 5 & b  \end{array} \right)\,,$$

and the eigenvector is $(-4,-6)$ associated to this eigenvalue $\lambda=6$.

Sorry for my English. I'm Chilean.

Comment: By definition, what does it mean for $6$ to be an eigenvalue?

Comment: the 6 is the  eigenvalue of the eigenvector (-4,6)

Comment: Use the definition of $\lambda$ i.e. $Av=\lambda v$. You are given $\lambda$ and $v$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\lambda = 6$ is an eigenvalue and $v = [-4 \;| -6]^\mathbf{T}$ is an eigenvector, then , by definition, it must be :

$$Av = \lambda v \implies \begin{pmatrix}6 & a \\ 5 & b \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -4\\-6\end{pmatrix}= 6\begin{pmatrix} -4\\-6\end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{cases} -24 -6a = -24 \\ -20 - 6b = -36 \end{cases} $$

Comment: @NelsonAguilera Your calculations are wrong. Solve the equations yielded more carefuly. It's just algebra.

Comment: Now I can understand the question. Thank you for help me.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for the heads up!

Comment: @egreg thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
u=\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
x=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
\qquad
v=\begin{pmatrix} -4 \\ -6 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then your data can be rewritten as
$$
-4u-6x=6v
$$
and therefore
$$
x=-\frac{2}{3}u-v
$$